# Friend the non-const templated version of class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, friend

Consider the following piece of code:

```
template<class T>
class Me {
private:
    T* data;
    size_t size;

    friend class Me<?????>;
public:
    Me(size_t s) : data(new T[s]), size(s) {}
    virtual ~Me() { delete [] data; }

    Me<T> operator= (const Me<T const>& rhs) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            data[i] = rhs.data[i]; // Gives compile error "data is a private member of Me<XX const>"
    }
}
```

Disregarding that this is a very contrived example, what is the right way to access a private data member of a version of the class differing only by constness of `T`?  If it were going the other way, I could simply do: `friend class Me<T const>;`

I don't want to expose a way to access the internal data pointer to the broader world (even via getter) in my real code.  Also, I'm not doing anything here that goes against const correctness, since I'll never modify the right-hand side of the equation.

Maybe this is totally all the wrong way to go about it, but it seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to do at the time.

Would the better thing to do be creating a free function?  E.g.

```
template<class T>
Me<T> operator= (const Me<T>& lhs, const Me<T const>& rhs) {...}
```

This second approach compiles fine, but gives me a link (Undefined symbols) error that I'm still tracing down.

Comment: fairly sure this is a duplicate...
`template<class> friend class FriendClass;` Will enable all specializations of `FriendClass` to be friends

Comment: @JosephFranciscus can you link if it is?  I spent a fair amount of time searching for this question. Maybe it's just difficult to word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the assignment operator of the class and a templated one that work on `Me<T const>` also give friendship to the no const version as:

```
template<class T>
class Me {
private:
    friend class Me<std::remove_const_t<T>>;
public:

    Me<T>& operator= (const Me<T>& rhs) {
        // ...
        return *this;
    }

    template <class U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, T const>, bool> = true>
    Me<T>& operator=(Me<U> const& rhs) {
        // ...
        return *this;
    }
};

Me<int> r;
Me<int const> l;
r = l;
```

Comment: I'm choosing this answer since it also shows off useful "enable_if" stuff.  It's a tricky thing, so I appreciate it being shown.  Main thing is I was unaware of std::remove_const, though.  Also, want to shout out to @JosephFranciscus for an alternate solution of `template<class> friend class FriendClass;` which might also be useful.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, wouldn't it be easier just to write 
`Me<T>& operator=(Me<const T> const& rhs)`?

Comment: @JosephFranciscus defining it like that will conflict when you try to instantiate `Me<int const>` as you can see it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38e03670392aa4bb).

Comment: @Jans *facepalms* good catch *Too tired to be on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a marginally better than the accepted answer, as it doesn't require overloading the assignment operator. Additionally this version will disable the assignment operator for `const T` types. (As you may not want to enable copying them anyway).

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T>
class Me {
private:
    friend class Me<std::remove_const_t<T>>;
public:

    template <class U>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::remove_const_t<U>, T>::value, Me<T>&>
    operator=(Me<U> const& rhs) {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {

    Me<int> r;
    Me<int const> l;

    r = l;
    r = r;
    l = l;

    l = r; //will cause compilation failure.
}
```

---

This version will support the assignment operator for `const T` types as well.

```
    template <class U>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::remove_const_t<U>, std::remove_const_t<T>>::value, Me<T>&>
    operator=(Me<U> const& rhs) {
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome!  Do you think there's any case where this would be 'worse' in some way than having the overload?

Comment: So then, it seems like this might actually be _better_, in that it wouldn't allow me to modify the const T contents via the operator= overload - right?  It's more restricted, perhaps in a good way.  Do you know of a good resource to dive into this more, it's making my head spin a bit.

Comment: Cppcon 2014 Walter Brown Template Metaprogramming: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY

He reviews most of the fundamentals of TMP. Though its not for the faint of heart/

Comment: @JosephFranciscus let point out a few things you got wrong, there's a difference between the assignment operator and the template version (the former always will be a better match for objects of the same class). both `A<T>` and `A<T const>` can be assigned to `A<T>` but `A<T const>` can only be assigned to `A<T const>` using the non-templated assignment, which was the OP intension. your second version is off topic... also check if the accepted answer do actually fail where you think it fail.

Comment: @Jans Unsure what you mean, I stated the accepted answer is less restrictive than my version and I never spoke to the accepted answer failing.

this: `the former always will be a better match for objects of the same class` is moot as its implied the implementation of `Me<T> operator=(const Me<T>&)` is expected to be the same as `Me<T> operator=(const Me<const T>&)`
 
This is true, `A<T const> can only be assigned to A<T const>` though I don't think the OP wanted to call the copy-operator on const objects. (Why would you want to copy const objects? Wouldn't the call fail anyway?)

Comment: @Jans Oh you're right nevermind. I'll edit my answer. Sorry about that

Comment: I deleted my original comment, as it was misleading and incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> right way to access a private data member of a version of the class differing only by constness of T?

What about

```
friend class Me<std::remove_const_t<T>>;
```

?

In your case it the `T` (no `const`) version that must access the private data of the `T const` version.

So you have to make friend the `T` (no `const`) version.

Off Topic suggestion: you tagged C++17, so you can use smart pointers.

Use them!

The default copy constructor and the default `operator=()` of your `Me` are very, very dangerous (double free of the same allocated memory almost guaranted).